# Ubuntu 22.04 Snap files shared with Skype

Tags: snap, skype, opera

After a recent update Opera no longer played any videos in my 16.04 LTS with ES
so I checked Opera in Ubuntu 22.04 with same result.
But looking through the Snap package for **Opera** {home/snap/opera/common/cache/opera/cache/cache-data} I find over 1000 binary files!
For example: 0a6d0afd66ab8e73_0   (7kb open with share w skype)
and 0c342c6186d44844_0  (232kb) up to  032f23e9aa79d3d0_s  (1.3MB) !!
Also in opera/default cache,  code cache and system cache there are many similar files that open Skype.
I do have Skype installed but have never used it in 22.04.
What are these files and should I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Files under `~/snap/` are user configuration files. These are created when you use the program, and contain personal configuration options, bookmarks, extensions, and also the browser cache.

To fully reset Opera to factory default, you can delete (or just move out) `~/snap/opera`. Be aware that any custom settings, bookmarks, etc, will be gone, so you may want to take your precautions and export your bookmarks first, so you can import them again later.

It is well possible that, with the factory default configuration, video will work again. If not, then you know it is a system wide issue, but you also know the 1000 of files you discovered were not at the origin of the problem. In that case, the issue may be related to your configuration, video drivers, hardware, etc.

Comment: Thanks,It was an opera update problem and video was restored, However it still leaves the question re the 1000+ files that are shared with and open Skype, Isit safe to delete these?